# Use Regex to print desired lines based on a value of a field in C sharp?

Tags: c#

In my log file there are mainly 3 types of values for field "appGUID" i.e. "wx" , "null" and value containing mix of chars and numbers. I want to filter out content in such a way that all the appGUID values containing either "wx" and "null" are stored in an empty new string and appGUID values containing mix of chars and numbers are discarded. 
 I am not able to figure out it's regex pattern. Please help.

My log file is of format :

> INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: wx INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: wx INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf

My code is here :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Karan Logs\20110717.txt");
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();
List<string> users = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"appGUID:\s*(?<value>.*?)\s");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var user = match.Groups["value"].Value;
    if (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: You may use `appGUID: (?<value>wx|null)`.

Comment: But are you sure that you want to capture the `appGUID`? Or you want the corresponding `User` for each log entry where `appGUID`'s value is `null` or `wx`? Just asking, because you seem to add the values you find to the `users` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `appGUID: (?<value>wx|null)`:

```
StreamReader reader =
    new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Karan Logs\20110717.txt");
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();
List<string> users = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"appGUID: (?<value>wx|null)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var user = match.Groups["value"].Value;
    if (!users.Contains(user))
        users.Add(user);
```